# Hide Attachments/More button Odoo 8

Tags: hide, attachment, odoo-8

I need to hide Attachments & More button from form view. is it possible?
if yes please give me solution..

Comment: You need to give us more details of what you really need.

Comment: There is a flag field with values of 1 and 0 . need to hide these button if  flag value 1 otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml, you need to define the your field flag where your button is, and add into the button's defination somethig like this: `attrs={'invisible':[('flag_fielf','=', False)]}` , that means if your flag is 0(False) your button is hidden, otherwise is visible.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for you reply juan. it works for user defined buttons, but i don't know where the code for  'Attachment' button is written. could you help me find it out?

Comment: And also i noticed , the attachment button is visible  only if the user access rights is  'Human resource/Manager', for all other roles the button hidden. i tried to find out the code for this rule, but can't?? Help plz..